# Were plans made for metrics associated with the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project?

Tags: discussion, se-quality-project

I'm excited to hear about the [Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285889/303080), and surprised by the pages of answers there!

Were plans made  for metrics or success criteria? Projects without good metrics of success can go sideways even with the best of intentions.

What about metrics, or ways to detect and measure issues with user experience?  A short questionnaire about user experience that's applies and is well-announced over all sites in the SE ecosystem would be great, but developing it would be a task for "objective impartial" people, maybe even an outside source.

I'm imagining lists of things that users appreciate most, and dislike the most, and the user would select up to 3 (or 5) *on a per-site basis*. It's the per-site basis I am most interested in, since experience with multiple, disparate sites helps to highlight the best that stackexchange can offer and where it can improve.

Is there a way to try to identify the greatest sources of user satisfaction, and the greatest sources of *user angst*?

Maybe it is ultimately impossible, but maybe not!