# What are the results of question reputation changes after one month?

Tags: discussion, support, reputation

More than month ago [question upvotes were changed in value from `+5` to `+10`](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/).

Right now we can talk about results/metrics and how it affected the community. I guess SE had assumptions before this change. And after one month of this experiment the company should have a conclusion about it.

Is SE planning to share this metrics/thoughts about rep changes with the community?

Comment: They are probably waiting to [assemble workgroups](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/11/the-loop-1-how-we-conduct-research-on-the-community-team/) (step 4).

Comment: *"And after one month of this experiment"* .... this isn't an experiment. They reverted the previous change from 10 to 5, because it didn't had the result they expected. So we can say the actual experiment ended with this revert.

Comment: currently unanswered: [Were plans made for metrics associated with the Second Iteration of the Stack Exchange Quality Project?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286348/303080)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Our motivation for the change was to recognize that both question askers and answerers are a vital part of our ecosystem and to reward them both equally.

Having examined the data from before and after the change, we haven’t seen any lasting impact (positive or negative) on voting behaviors for questions or answers, question quality, answer rates, or usage rates of privileges. For about a month after the recalc, we saw that downvoting did go up on both questions and answers, but it returned to previous levels by January 2020 and has been stable since.

So in the end, while it would've been great to see some clearly positive outcomes here, there's no lasting negative impact, and I'd say that the change achieved its intended goal.

Answer (score 14):

The blog you linked to does not include any assumption about the effects of a change, other than *maybe*

> For those of you that are getting new privileges: we ask you to take the responsibility reverently. You are the question experts. You are the people that can identify a question that is struggling and you know how hard it can be to on the other side of that keyboard. Thank you in advance for gently coaching question askers through their experience.

That sounds too vague to be clearly measured, even if you have access to extensive A/B testing and the full Stack Exchange database rather than SEDE.

A reasonable and measurable assumption would have been something like 'we expect more (or less) upvotes on questions' or 'we expect an increase in question quality', but nothing has been communicated so far. I think this change was made because it only seemed fair to the company, rather than with a concrete benefit in mind (other than the straightforward increase in reputation for most users).